# Vuejs 2.3 - Sync and Element Ui Dialog

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using `Element UI` and things have changed since the release of `Vue.js 2.3`

I have a `dialog` that should be displayed only if the following condition is met `private.userCanManageUsers && private.pendingUsers.length > 0 && private.pendingDialogVisible`

I'm trying to use the new attribute `visible.sync` [documentation here](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/dialog)

It is working if the condition contains only one condition but does not work with several.

### Working

```
<el-dialog
       :visible.sync="private.pendingDialogVisible"                 
</el-dialog>
```

### Not working

```
<el-dialog
       :visible.sync="private.userCanManageUsers && private.pendingUsers.length > 0 && private.pendingDialogVisible"           
    </el-dialog>
```

1. What is the solution to use the `el-dialog` with `visible.sync` with
   several condition?
2. If this is impossible what should I do to make it work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is caused by a misunderstanding of what `sync` is actually doing.

In Vue 2.3 (unlike in Vue 1x), `sync` is nothing more than an event registration to facilitate two-way binding.  Per the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier):

> In 2.3 we re-introduced the .sync modifier for props, but this time it
> is just syntax sugar that automatically expands into an additional
> v-on listener:
> The following
>
> `<comp :foo.sync="bar"></comp>`
>
> is expanded into:
>
> `<comp :foo="bar" @update:foo="val => bar = val"></comp>`

What does this mean in layman's terms?  Since it is facilitating two-way binding to update the value being sync'd upon, you cannot use multiple properties (as a boolean expression), nor can you use the return value of a method since you ***must*** both read from and write to the same value.

In short, no, you cannot accomplish using `sync` in the way you are currently utilizing it and I personally disagree with the implementation that the library has chosen since it isn't particularly clear and forces complicated workarounds.

That said, you can use a single property for binding the visibility of `:visible.sync` and you can trigger that based on your state [in the following example](https://jsfiddle.net/g1h2v3zL/1/):

**Template:**

```
<div id="app">
  <el-dialog title="Shipping address" :visible.sync="showDialog" 
    :before-close="beforeCloseHandler"
    @close="cond1 = true; cond2 = false;">
  </el-dialog>
  <button @click="cond1 = true; cond2 = false; showDialog = true;">Open Dialog</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        showDialog: true,
        cond1: true,
        cond2: true,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      beforeCloseHandler: function (done) {
        if (this.cond1 && this.cond2) {
            console.log('hit close');
            done();
        } else {
            console.log('rejected close');
        }
      }
    }
  };
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

We can bind the display to a single property and we can control dismissing with the `:before-close` handler and of course we can control our show conditions via a click event on a button. It isn't perfect, but it is a potential workaround.